# Не знаю(,) на чём

Tags: запятые

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужны ли те запятые? Я знаю, что, если союзное слово одно, оно не обособляется, но в этих примерах оно ещё же-с с предлогом используется-таки, поэтому я и-то сомневаюсь, что не надо запятой.

1. Я не знаю, как туда добраться, и не знаю(,) на чём.
2. Я хочу в парк, но я не знаю(,) с кем.
3. Кот-то в ящике, но никто не знает-таки(,) в каком-с.

Comment: Разные по структуре предложения: я не знаю, как туда добраться, на чём / я не хочу в парк - с кем?/кот-то в ящике, - но в каком-с? То есть два вопроса, и мне кажется разные, и одно утверждение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая не нужна.

1)Я не знаю, как туда добраться, и не знаю **на чём.**

2)Я хочу в парк, но я не знаю **с кем.**

3)Кот-то в ящике, но никто не знает-таки **в каком-с.**

**Правило**:

> *Запятая между главной частью и придаточной, присоединяемой простым союзом или союзным словом, не ставится: в) если придаточная часть
> усечена до одного союзного слова (одиночно употребленное союзное слово
> теряет функцию придаточного предложения): Учащимся назначили экзамен,
> но не уточнили когда; Со стороны проспекта кто-то шел — издали было
> неясно кто (Пелев.);*

***Пример из НКРЯ:***

— Кузя, смотри, там море, — перевела бабушка. — Правда, **не знаю где.** Ей, разумеется, было немного трудно говорить, жемчужины оттягивали обе щеки и немного постукивали о зубы. [Людмила Петрушевская. Город Света // «Октябрь», 2003]

Comment: Упорные слухи о Курске, не знаю, на чем основанные.

Comment: Лучше так: Упорные слухи о Курске:  основанные на чем-то, но не знаю – на чем?

Comment: Ну это я с нацкорпуса взял, не сам придумал.

Answer (score 1):

В этих примерах запятая не нужна, но в общем случае это зависит от структуры предложения. Предлог **не оказывает существенного влияния**, так как **исключения** из основного правила возможны по-прежнему.

Например:

(1) **Основное правило:** *Я не знаю, как туда добраться, и **не знаю на чём**.*

**Пример с предлогом**: Ф. М. Достоевский. Братья Карамазовы (1880)
*Потому поссорились, что когда он объявил мне, что в случае осуждения Дмитрий Федорович убежит за границу вместе с той тварью, то я вдруг озлилась — не скажу вам **из-за чего**, сама не знаю **из-за чего**...*

(2) **Исключение**: *Я знаю кАк туда добраться, **не знАю — на чЁм?**.*

**У [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137)** есть похожее исключение, пункт 4(3): *Одно время он что-то шептал, не могли понять — **что**?* (А. Т.) — постановка тире подчеркивает значение местоимения и оправдывается вопросительной интонацией.